# Business Continuity Plan for web application and database

Tags: disaster-recovery

I have been asked by work to set up a business continuity/disaster recovery plan for two similarly implemented web applications and associated databases.

Not something I'm familiar with doing.

What are the best practice procedures for creating plans of this nature?

Comment: Don't forget that in a DR situation backups are useless - it's *restores* that you need. Test the full chain from off-site vault to operational application regularly. The cost of getting those tapes back is nothing compared to the cost if it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Business Continuity can be a complicated beast and you'll need to involve affected departments/users to make sure everyone knows the 'plan'.  The main two things you'll tend to see over and over are: RTO (Recovery Time Objective) and RPO (Recovery Point Objective)

RTO basically is the maximum time allowed to get things back to 'normal' or at least functioning.  You would need to take into consideration small problems (server went down) to big problems (the building just exploded).

RPO basically is, how much data could we 'possibly' lose should a bad problem happen?  5 minutes, 1 hour, 1 day, NONE?

There are lots of good stuff on the Internet about this topic - I think it would be time well spent doing some internet searches for IT Business Continuity Plan.

Here are a couple of good articles right off the bat:

http://www.cio.com/article/2381021/best-practices/how-to-create-an-effective-business-continuity-plan.html

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/new-high-availability-planning-worksheet/

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/letters-that-get-dbas-fired/

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/09/why-rpo-and-rto-are-actually-performance-metrics-too/